# Where can I download the entire Monero blockchain in one shot?

Tags: blockchain

Monero syncing via the daemon can take days/weeks. Where can I download the entire 50GB+ monero blockchain from a fast connection?

Comment: Why does it take days/weeks ? Do you have a a slow HD ? If so, downloading the chain won't help. It'd only help if the bottleneck is your network connection to other peers, and somehow the blockchain.raw download site is faster, but that's unlikely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current blockchain can be downloaded from https://downloads.getmonero.org/blockchain.raw

Comment: Do I have to unzip this .raw file or just copy it to my .bitmonero folder's root directory? What do I do with this after downloading it?

Comment: https://www.getmonero.org/resources/user-guides/importing_blockchain.html

Comment: @jtgrassie is there an alternative source like torrent? Because sometimes, the speed of server decrease and becomes very very low.

Comment: There's really no point to use the .raw file these days. Better to just let the daemon sync the blockchain from the p2p nodes.

Comment: Why didn't they post lmdb insted? You need to wait import after downloading, which is slow as hell.